# How can I copy nodes from one xml file into another?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode, insertafter

I would like to copy a parent node and children nodes from one xml file to another. In the example below, I would like to copy Items from file #2 into file #1:

Input file #1:

```
<Top>
  <Items>
    <Item>one</Item>
    <Item>two</Item>
  </Items>
</Top>
```

Input file #2:

```
<Top>
  <Items>
    <Item>three</Item>
    <Item>four</Item>
  </Items>
</Top>
```

I want the final XML file to look like the following:

```
<Top>
  <Items>
    <Item>one</Item>
    <Item>two</Item>
  </Items>
  <Items>
    <Item>three</Item>
    <Item>four</Item>
  </Items>
</Top>
```

I attempted the following non-functional code. The InsertAfter call does not work across xml files. Any help?

```
XmlDocument prev = new XmlDocument(); prev.Load(filename1);
XmlDocument curr = new XmlDocument(); curr.Load(filename2);
XmlNode prev_node = prev.SelectSingleNode("Items");
XmlNode curr_node = curr.SelectSingleNode("Items");
prev.InsertAfter(curr_node, prev_node);
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML:

```
var prev = XDocument.Load(filename1);
var curr = XDocument.Load(filename2);
prev.Root.Add(curr.Root.Elements());
```

Comment: Perfect! I won't admit how much time I spent on this last night to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much.. @MarcinJuraszek..And I want insert root node also..Please tell me..